# why dim of colMeans/rowMeans return null?

Tags: r, null, mean

I am new to R. I have the following code

```
sigma1  = matrix(c(2,0,0,1),2,2)
mu1     = matrix(c(0,10),2,1)

x1      = t(mvrnorm(n = 5, mu1, sigma1))

print(rowMeans(x1))
print(dim(colMeans(x1)))
```

and for some reason I get NULL for dimension of row/col means.

Comment: Because `?rowMeans` says it returns a vector if the result is one-dimensional, and vectors don't have dims.

Comment: ..so you would use `length(1:5)` for vectors or (confusingly) `NROW(1:5)` but not `nrow(1:5)` and neither `ncol(1:5)` and _definitely not_ `NCOL(1:5)`

Comment: how can I force R to treat vectors like matrices permanently then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'as.matrix' turns the vector 'colMeans(x1)' into a matrix. Then the dimensions are 5 and 1, as expected:

```
library(rockchalk)

sigma1  = matrix(c(2,0,0,1),2,2)
mu1     = matrix(c(0,10),2,1)
x1      = t(mvrnorm(n = 5, mu1, sigma1))

print(rowMeans(x1))
print(dim(colMeans(x1)))
print(dim(as.matrix(colMeans(x1))))
```

Output:

```
> print(rowMeans(x1))
[1] -0.1518187  9.4232239

> print(dim(colMeans(x1)))
NULL

> print(dim(as.matrix(colMeans(x1))))
[1] 5 1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to coerce a vector into a matrix, you could try something like:

```
##  Initial Computations.
sigma1  = matrix(c(2,0,0,1),2,2)
mu1 = matrix(c(0,10),2,1)
x1 = t(mvrnorm(n = 5, mu1, sigma1))

##  Coerce the vector of colMeans into a 1 by 5 matrix.
colmeans.x1 = rbind(colMeans(x1))

##  Inspect the dimensions of the matrix created above.
dim(colmeans.c1)
```

Hope that helps...