# How to find if a vector is column vector or a row vector in R

Tags: r, vector, dimension

I want to know if a vector is 1xN or Nx1 in R. What function should I use? Length returns only one value regardless of the vector type.

Comment: `vector`s don't have `dim`ensions. `matrix` or `data.frame` or `table` objects do though... have you tried `dim` ?

Comment: Dim returns null. Wondering what is the mathematically equivalent of a vector in R then? One can transpose a vector so logically there should be a way to distinguish them

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but why would it be expected that a vector should be `1xN` or `Nx1`? - it's just length `N` without any higher order dimensions.

Comment: This seems pretty unclear, but maybe you want to look into `NROW` and `NCOL` (yes, capitalized).

Comment: @AnandaMahto - indeed - to quote `?NROW` - *`nrow` and `ncol` return the number of rows or columns present in ‘x’.  `NCOL` and `NROW` do the same **treating a vector as 1-column matrix.***

Comment: See rawr's comment on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258101/why-dim-of-colmeans-rowmeans-return-null)

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks just out of curiosity is there a function that returns both of them?

Answer (score 4):

As AnandaMahto's comment, using NROW/NCOL it returns numbers of rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

In R, vectors don't have dimensions. The dimension of a vector is `NULL`. Whereas, arrays, matrices, data frames, tables have dimensions.

If you want to know the value of `N`(that is the number of elements in a vector) you can use the length function

Comment: `m <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4); dim(m[1,])` gives `NULL`.

Comment: When I told 1*N I meant through a row of a matrix you can know how many columns are there and similarly through N*1, we can know how many rows are there in that particular column. I Should have been little clear. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks @Minions I am already aware of the length function and I mentioned it in my question, what I am wondering is if there is difference between row or column vectors as R treats them differently.